# How to delete a site column via Javascript/JSOM

Tags: javascript, jsom, site-column, delete

Is there a way to delete a site column (and remove it from all according content types) via Javascript? I found some CSOM scripts and tried to approximate the JSOM method but it didn't work out. The methods seem to be slightly different.

-thanks a lot

```
deleteSiteColumn = function(columnSTR) {
    myList.init();      
    var fieldOBJ = myList.webContextOBJ.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(columnSTR);
    myList.clientContextOBJ.load(fieldOBJ);
    myList.clientContextOBJ.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        fieldOBJ.deleteObject();
        myList.webContextOBJ.update();
        myList.clientContextOBJ.executeQueryAsync(function() {
            console.log("Site Column '" + columnSTR + "' deleted");
        }, function(senderOBJ, argsOBJ) {
            console.log('Failed: ' + argsOBJ.get_message());
        });     
    }, function(senderOBJ, argsOBJ) {
        console.log('Failed: ' + argsOBJ.get_message());
    });     
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code that you have tried already

Comment: Sorry, I actually hadn't much code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not posted your existing code!! It is always welcome if you post what you have tried so far. Anyway find my code for deleting site column

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var web = clientContext.get_web();
var field = web.get_fields().getByTitle('{Display Name of Site Column}');
clientContext.load(field);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    field.deleteObject();
    web.update();
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        console.log("Site Column deleted");
    }, function() {
        // handle error
    });


}, function() {
    // handle error
});
```

**PS:** If your site column is being used in any content types then you will get an error.

Comment: It's not working... He executes the queries and logs the "deleted" message, but the columns are still there (they are not in use, neither in a list nor in a content type).
(I posted my method, based on your code)

Comment: Just tested my code again! It works. Can you test my code in console?

Comment: Hmmm mine to if I execute the funtion seperatly... But if I use it in a loop, to delete several columns at once it won't.

Comment: in loop approach is little different but it must work. Show your code how you are trying

Comment: oh got the error... I used a global ClientContext. They proberbly overwrote each other...

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove the columns from the according content type? Or do I have to loop through every Content Type and check if the field is part of it?

Comment: you need to remove from content type at first the from site column